# Errors running sqlite through adb shell

Tags: android, sqlite, command-line, adb

Running from the command-line on a Windows 10 PC, and I'm having a problem with quotation marks:

- `adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies 'select count(*) from cookies;'"`

  - sush: syntax error: '(' unexpected
- `adb shell su -c sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies 'select count(*) from cookies;'`

  - sush: syntax error: '(' unexpected
- `adb shell su -c sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies "select count(*) from cookies;"`

  - /system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
- I tried a query which didn't contain parens, but that wouldn't run either:

  - `adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies 'select * from cookies;'"`

    - Error: near "select": syntax error
- I can run other sqlite3 commands from the adb shell

  - `adb shell su -c "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies .schema"`

    - that works with or without quotation marks.

And going into ADB shell works:

```
>adb shell
/ $ su
/ # sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies 'select count(*) from cookies;'
3238
```

**I simply want to get the results of a query from the command-line.**
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
adb shell su -c sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies "\"select count(*) from cookies;\""
```

or

```
query="\"select count(*) from cookies;\""
adb shell su -c sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Cookies "$query"
```

I guess the problem is with the double quotes. I am still not quite sure why those double quotes are needed within the query, but this is most certainly to work.